# Unable to setup connection between iPhone Proxy and Postman Proxy debug

Tags: ios, proxy, postman

I want to track network traffic of mobile app in iPhone using Postman.
According to Postman article (https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/) I setup it on between Postman App and my iPhone. But when I setup manual proxy in iPhone and try to access web application. Then my wifi disconnected and can't see any network traffic.
Anyone knows how to enable wifi connection and capture network traffic ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with HTTP and succeeded with HTTPS by airdropping the postman certificate to my Iphone and enabling it.

I copied the following instructions from this article: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-https-traffic/

**To install the security certificate on iOS, do the following:**

1. Download the postman-proxy-ca.crt certificate to the iOS device (for example, using AirDrop). You can find the certificate file on your computer in the following location:

- macOS - ~/Library/Application Support/Postman/proxy
- Windows - C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Postman\proxy
- Linux - ~/.config/Postman/proxy
  Go to Settings > Profile Downloaded, and then select Install. Enter your passcode to proceed.

2. A security warning displays. Select Install.
3. After the certificate is installed, select Done.
4. Go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings.
5. Enable full trust for Postman’s root certificate, and select Continue to complete the installation.